# Can I please see my deleted questions?

Tags: discussion

I would really appreciate it. I want to learn from my mistakes and perhaps ask there somewhere else more appropriate.

Look, I've tried hard to improve. As you see, my last question is still closed, even though I no longer bashing feminism (I got bored of that too actually).

Sometimes certain things that's not "fit in" my expected norm makes me very curious. It feels funny, so I ask. I didn't mean to be hostile. Illogical things honestly feel funny to me.

In short, I got a kick out of asking them.

Comment: I have posted your deleted questions. I want to add that this forum is not a place to merely post 'jokes' or 'humorous rhetoric.'

Comment: My bad :). Anyway thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to answer this in 2 big posts of 5 deleted questions each. I want to add a bit subjectively that I do this because I think that everyone should always be able to see their own content. I would be surprised if you could salvage many of the questions into something that the community would find fitting. But that also doesn't mean that you shouldn't try, I suppose.

I encourage you to read some of the questions and answers already on the site, as well as the [faq](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/faq), before you begin to pose any more questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So, we can't see the comments on those questions? I think that'll help a lot too.

Comment: This is good enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> ### Why feminists believe that no women can consent to prostitution?
>
> What about if client is justin bieber? How many prostitution are actually consensual?
>
> [social-contract](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-contract)
>
> *Originally posted 28 November 2011*

---

> ### Is marriage consensual?
>
> Force marriage is rape<sup>[how is this true?]</sup>. Well rape is usage of force in getting sex. Force marriage is forcing women to marry which then grant the men right to have sex with her. At least that's how it works in most countries that still practice forced marriage like afganistan.
>
> 1. Even in a very **liberal** country like Germany, prostitution is taxed.
> 2. Tax is game theory equivalent of a **fine**.
> 3. A **fine** is a form of punishment.
> 4. Existence of a punishment means prohibition<sup>[just because a tax is equal to a fine in terms of monetary loss does not mean you can appropriately suggest that a tax is a punishment]</sup>. Tax is equivalent with monetary lost and hence effectively punishment. Otherwise, government can easily break its constitution by calling something equivalent differently. Can't prohibit freedom of speech. Fine. Just tax speech $1 million dollars and poof there goes freedom of speech.
> 5. Prohibition of something means enforcement of the alternative.
> 6. The great alternative to prostitution is marriage<sup>[how exactly is this an "alternative" to prostitution? What do you mean by alternative?]</sup>. Marriage is a substitute product of prostitution. It has positive cross elasticity with prostitution. Raising price of prostitute would increase demand for marriage. Check https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/688/are-prostitution-and-marriage-substitutes
> 7. **Therefore**, all marriage is forced marriage. Which is rape.
>
> Basically by taxing prostitution, the German government effectively provides forceful incentive to get married.
>
> Another easy way to see this is to observe that there will be far less marriage if prostitution is tax free.
>
> Most other countries are far less liberal than Germany. In Afghanistan, sex outside marriage is illegal effectively forcing anyone wanting to have sex to get married.
>
> **Can we conclude then that all marriage is non consensual?**
>
> Comparison:
>   Looks to me it depends on what count as consent.
>
> 1. Income tax is also not consensual even though you can avoid it by not making any income. So the fact that you can simply avoid marriage by not having sex or
>      not paying prostitution tax may not make marriage consensual.
> 2. However, by the same logic, taxing Japanese car would make all purchase of US' car
>      non consensual, which is absurd. However, we know that there will be
>      far less US cars sold if Japanese cars don't pay import taxes.
>
> [ethic](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ethic) [rule-ethics](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rule-ethics)
>
> *Originally posted 5 December 2011*

---

> ### How do we treat cases where someone think someone else make a bad choice and prohibit it?
>
> Say a person, Angie. She has a preference to be a paid sugar baby by a handsome tall multi millionaire that already have 50 beautiful girl friends. She also prefer to consume a non addictive safe drug like ecstasy.
>
> And then we have Bob. He thinks doing that is bad for Angie and prohibit prostitution and ecstasy.
>
> Now economists usually believe that humans maximize their selfish interests (homo economicus). How do we reconcile between homo economicus and Angie's apparent preference to pick an outcome that Bob think is bad for her
>
> 1. Bob is right. Being a sugar baby and eating ecstasy is bad for Angie. But that's what Angie prefer. So we conclude that Angie prefers something that's bad for her.
> 2. Being a sugar baby and eating ecstasy is actually good for Angie, but somehow bad for Bob. So homo economicus is still right. We simply have a case of typical power struggle.
>
> Which one or other ways you think will be a way to resolve this apparent contradiction.
>
> Note: I am picking a sample a handsome tall smart multi millionaires. I think it's easier to accept that picking a handsome tall smart multi millionaire is consensual so I used that as a sample. That's because it's still prostitution and many people think that prostitution can't possibly consensual. The truth is: Handsome short multimulionaire would cut it. Ugly short multimilionaire would still cut it. In fact, hordes of ugly short horny fapping poor males would still cut it and that would eliminate all war and violent in the world I think. At least it's not illegal to have sex or even get knocked up by those losers for free. However I am picking a sample where it's obvious that the girl is consenting despite engaging in prostitution. So yes, selling sex to a handsome tall multimilionaire still count as prostitution. As we know, many people think that prostitution can't possibly be consensual. So how do we think? Do we think that it's still bad for Angie? Do we think it's not consensual? How do we define and consent anyway self interest?
>
> [philosophy-of-economics](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/philosophy-of-economics)
>
> *Originally posted 21 December 2011*

---

> ### Can we know true intent of societies/voters/politicians?
>
> In wikipedia for women trafficking there are many different theories that explain why women trafficking is prohibited
>
> 1. Women trafficking is an exploitation and must be prohibited despite consent to protect the trafficked women's interest.
> 2. Women in rich country do not want to compete with cheaper women from poorer countries
>
> The same way for prostitution there are distinct theories that explain why it's prohibited
>
> 1. Prostitution can't be consensual (despite consent) and must be prohibited to protect the prostitutes
> 2. Many women actually prefer to be a prostitute than a wife. Evolutionary psychology, for example, says that women often prefer to share a rich smart male than be the only one for the poor ones. The former can't be done within marriage. Hence, prostitution and polygamy is prohibited not to protect the prostitute, but to protect men that can't compete with rich paying men that many women actually do prefer. Some people here think that way http://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/krdd8/why_is_polygamy_illegal/
> 3. Religious and political leaders want to be the pimp of all women to control the population to ensure that they, and those wanting bigger government, get the prettiest girls. Hence, leaders prohibit many consensual acts to control who get the girls.
>
> The same way for drug prohibition there are differint theories
>   1. Drug is dangerous and hence must be prohibited. Some drugs like ecstasy is far less dangerous than cigarettes or alcohol but this is just misunderstanding on the part of government.
>   2. Government want to control fun and prevent happiness so government can grow bigger increasing governments' officials' salary/kickback/bribe.
>
> Which one is right? How do we know which one is correct? Should we ask a sceptic, economists?
>
> Okay there are different theories that explain the same observation. How do we know which one is correct and which one is wrong? How do we know what typically motivate voters?
>
> Are these things knowable?
>
> [philosophy-of-science](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/philosophy-of-science) [science](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science)
>
> *Originally posted 6 December 2011*

---

> ### You got two job offers. How should you decide?
>
> 1. The first one is from Britney Spears and Christina Aguilera. She offered you a job for having sex with them regularly to help them conceive.
> 2. The second one is from US government. They want you to fight some Taliban/Canibal Amazon combo in Afghanistan or something.
>
> Job #1 pays 5 times as much.
>
> Which one you will choose?
>
> Which one most males would choose?
>
> Which one would most females on equivalent situation will choose?
>
> So why do feminists want women to be able to pick the 2nd option but not the first again?
>
> [philosophy-of-economics](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/philosophy-of-economics)
>
> *Originally posted 27 November 2011*

There was an 'answer' that you had accepted to this question. If you'd like it, we can include that too. But - it didn't actually answer the question.

---

Answer (score 1):

> ### Why is Sugar Babies is considered Prostitution, Illegal, and “Wrong” and Why Other Simmilar Arrangement is Not?
>
> There are 3 distinct definition of prostitution I presented here. The legal definition is so broad it can be used to prohibit all sex and all consideration. I am not the only one confused check: http://sugarbabydaily.com/tag/prostitute also this is not similar to my previous questions. This is about sugar babies and not prostitution in general.
>
> Look I used to study math and is used to more robust definitions of things. So this is indeed confusing to me okay.
>
> Definition on the webster says that prostitution is :  the act or practice of engaging in promiscuous sexual relations especially for money
>
> The word "especially" is vague so we can remove that from definition and comeback to that latter.
>
> Sugar babies are not promiscuous. Also sluts are not usually considered prostitute. So why are sugar babies considered prostitution and sluts are not?
>
> Wikipedia definition says: Prostitution is the act or practice of providing sexual services to another person in return for payment.
>
> Well, marriage does pay. Just ask ex wife of Beatty Chadwick http://freebeattychadwick.blogspot.com/. So why marriage is not prostitution while being a sugar baby is?
>
> Finally the legal definition of prostitution is: The law says prostitution is "a lewd act for money or other consideration" - http://www.coyotela.org/getarrestedinfo.html
>
> This is a very broad definition. What kind of sex is there that's done without "consideration"?
>
> Also lewd is defined as "the touching of breast, buttocks or genitals for the purpose of sexual gratification or arousal." Okay, let me try to understand here. If lewd acts are illegal, how do you guys have sex out there anyway? How do you get babies?
>
> Why sex within marriage is not considered lewd?
>
> More importantly, why is it wrong to have "consideration" when deciding to have sex with someone?
>
> [ethics](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ethics)
>
> *Originally posted 24 February 2012*

---

> ### What Would be the Politically Correct Answer to the Question “Are all women sex objects?
>
> Yes or no?
>
> Which one :D
>
> I am just curious. I am trying to learn how to get along with feminists here.
>
> [political-philosophy](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/political-philosophy)
>
> *Originally posted 24 February 2012*

---

> ### Why do free masons want to promote their beliefs on supreme being?
>
> What are the interests of the free masons?
>
> Are they promoting monotheism? Deism? How can one join them?
>
> [theology](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theology)
>
> *Originally posted 28 November 2011*

---

> ### What's the mathematical/logical explanation (if any) of various trigam in I-Ching?
>
> There are 8 trigrams in I-Ching.
>
> Heaven, Thunder, Fire, Valley, Earth, Wind, Water, and Mountain, as it's usually represented by the circular arrangement in some book like http://www.wdprofiletest.com/.
>
> Well, heaven is represented by 111 (from bottom to up),Thunder is 100, Fire is 101, Valley is 110, Earth is 000, Wind is 011, Water is 010, and Mountain is 001.
>
> Now, can anyone explain to me how the numbers match the trigram?
>
> I can imagine Heaven is 111 because it gets their way no matter what. I can imagine thunder as in surprise attack; simply strike first and then get flexible (yin) on the latter stage of the situation.
>
> I can see that mountains resemble people that let things happen and act assertively at the end; after all, the fact shows.
>
> But how can fire and everything else be explained?
>
> I tried to see this in context of hawk and dove games and repeated prisoner dilemma. I don't quite see it. I wonder if any mathematician can see the behind the code or is there other studies about this or something?
>
> [philosophy-of-mathematics](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/philosophy-of-mathematics)
>
> *Originally posted 24 February 2012*

---

> ### What's the difference between monotheism and polytheism?
>
> I know that polytheism means beliefs in many God.
>
> However, look at polytheistic religion.
>
> One God is on top. Zeus ubber alles.
>
> The same way in monotheistic judaism, one God is on top too. YHWH ubber alles.
>
> Another is that in polytheistic religion the underling gods are called gods too.
>
> But what's the difference between that and angels in judeo christian traditions? The angels are like the gods in polytheistic religion, namely capable to do godly acts though not almighty.
>
> [theology](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theology)
>
> *Originally posted 28 November 2011*